# Ruby on Rails Deployment to Server resulting in old Wrapper Scripts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to deploy my RoR Application to an Ubuntu (Latest Version with Updates) Server. 
The Application will run with the Gem "Passenger". However, i am unable to run Passenger.

```
rvmsudo bundle exec passenger start
```

results in:

```
Your RVM wrapper scripts are too old, or some wrapper scripts are 
missing. Please update/regenerate them first by running:

rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvmsudo rvm repair all

If that doesn't seem to work, please run:

rvmsudo rvm wrapper ruby-2.6.3 --no-prefix --all
```

I've tried everything and yes i acctually executed those command. Both not resulting in and sucessfull deployment.

I even wiped the whole server and tried it from scratch. It does not work.

First results in this output:

```
rvmsudo rvm get stable && rvm reload && rvmsudo rvm repair all
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer.asc
Verifying /usr/share/rvm/archives/rvm-installer.asc
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/cloud/.gnupg'
gpg: Signature made Tue Jul 23 21:59:45 2019 UTC
gpg:                using RSA key 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: Good signature from "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 7D2B AF1C F37B 13E2 069D  6956 105B D0E7 3949 9BDB
GPG verified '/usr/share/rvm/archives/rvm-installer'
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.9.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.9/1.29.9.tar.gz.asc
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/cloud/.gnupg'
gpg: Signature made Wed Jul 10 08:31:02 2019 UTC
gpg:                using RSA key 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: Good signature from "Piotr Kuczynski <piotr.kuczynski@gmail.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 7D2B AF1C F37B 13E2 069D  6956 105B D0E7 3949 9BDB
GPG verified '/usr/share/rvm/archives/rvm-1.29.9.tgz'
Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/share/rvm/
    Fixing environment link for default.
    Fixing environment for ruby-2.6.3.
Upgrade of RVM in /usr/share/rvm/ is complete.
  * Please do NOT forget to add your users to the rvm group.
     The installer no longer auto-adds root or users to the rvm group. Admins must do this.
     Also, please note that group memberships are ONLY evaluated at login time.
     This means that users must log out then back in before group membership takes effect!
  * WARNING: you have set GEM_HOME="/home/cloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3"
     This is conflicting with RVM. Make sure to call:

           unset GEM_HOME


Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate


RVM reloaded!
RVM reloaded!
Repairing symlinks...
Symlinks repaired
Repairing archives...
Archives repaired
Regenerating environments...
Environments regenerated
Regenerating all wrappers...
Regenerating wrappers for ruby-2.6.3.......................................................................................
Regenerating wrappers for ruby-2.6.3@global........................................................................................
Wrappers regenerated
```

And second command results in this:

```
Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.9 (latest) (c) 2009-2017 Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin

# Wrapper

Show/regenerate wrappers.

NOTE: This command delegates to 'gem wrapper' => <https://github.com/rvm/gem-wrappers>

## Usage

Show paths and generated wrappers:

    rvm wrapper show


Show path to generated wrapper:

    rvm wrapper show executable_name

Where `executable_name` is something like `ruby` or `rake`.


It is also possible to generate a wrapper for external scripts that require ruby:

    rvm wrapper /full/path/to/script

Where `/full/path/to/script` is full path to existing script


Wrappers are generated automatically, but it is possible to rerun the process:

    rvm wrapper regenerate


Documentation:

    rvm wrapper [help]

For additional documentation please visit https://rvm.io
```

I did also try to update the whole thing, but this does not work.

Any help?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old but I found it googling myself.  I don't know the recommended solution but what I'm doing now is switching back & forth between rvm 1.28 (to create the wrapper) & 1.29 (to do everything else).  It's a PITA & I think not well thought out by the RVM maintainers.  They say it's supposed to be fixed/improved in 1.30.